# how to extract value of two properties into an array from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, es6-modules

Hi have an array of  object with 4 properties, i need to extract only 2 from them.

sample array of object

```
const arr=[
    module:{
     module1:{
       foo: 1,
       bar: 2,
       anotherfoo: 5
     }, module2:{
       foo: 3,
       bar: 4,
       anotherfoo: 8
     },module3:{
       foo: 7,
       bar: 6,
       anotherfoo: 3
     },module4:{
        submodule{
       foo: 9,
       bar: 0,
       anotherfoo: 1
       }
      }
      }];
```

How can I use map to extract module1 and module4.submodule into a new array.

Comment: Your example array currently doesn't function as it's invalid syntax. Please fix it.

Comment: `const newArray = [ arr[0], arr[3].submodule ]` ?

Comment: I have fixed now thanks

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I want to iterate and get new array out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a specific key when [destructuring an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Error:

```
const { module4.submodule } = { module4: { submodule: 4 } };
```

Good:

```
const { module4: { submodule } = { module4: { submodule: 4 } };
```

Same applies for creating an object, you can't return `{ module4.submodule }`, but you could return `{ module4Submodule: submodule }`.

Here's some potential solutions:

**Input: Array, Output: Array**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    module: {
      module1: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        anotherfoo: 5
      },
      module2: {
        foo: 3,
        bar: 4,
        anotherfoo: 8
      },
      module3: {
        foo: 7,
        bar: 6,
        anotherfoo: 3
      },
      module4: {
        submodule: {
          foo: 9,
          bar: 0,
          anotherfoo: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

const newArr = arr.map(({ module: { module1, module4 } }) => (
  { module1, module4Submodule: module4.submodule }
));

console.log(newArr);
```

**Input: Object, Output: Object**

```js
const obj = {
  module: {
    module1: {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2,
      anotherfoo: 5
    },
    module2: {
      foo: 3,
      bar: 4,
      anotherfoo: 8
    },
    module3: {
      foo: 7,
      bar: 6,
      anotherfoo: 3
    },
    module4: {
      submodule: {
        foo: 9,
        bar: 0,
        anotherfoo: 1
      }
    }
  }
};

const { module: { module1, module4: { submodule } } } = obj;
const newObj = { module1, module4Submodule: submodule };

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I dont want to destructure, i want to just iterate through this and get new array module1 and submodule

Comment: You're destructuring here: `arr.module.map(({module1, module4.submodule}) => 
 ({module1, module4.submodule}));`

Comment: i just tried that, let me correct my description updated my question

Comment: Added a potential solution, to show how you can use destructuring properly.

Comment: What about if it just an object not any array??

Comment: You want the output to be an object?

Comment: just assume it is not any array just an object, so how do we iterate and get module1 and module 4 data

Comment: Here is my object

module: {
      module1: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        anotherfoo: 5
      },
      module2: {
        foo: 3,
        bar: 4,
        anotherfoo: 8
      },
      module3: {
        foo: 7,
        bar: 6,
        anotherfoo: 3
      },
      module4: {
        submodule: {
          foo: 9,
          bar: 0,
          anotherfoo: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Added object to object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224218/discussion-between-r9102-and-jballin).

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `getDotPath` for object

```js
const getDotPath = (dotPath, obj) => {
  try {
    return dotPath.split(".").reduce((acc, prop) => acc[prop], obj)
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined
  }
}

const arr = [
  {
    module: {
      module1: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        anotherfoo: 5,
      },
      module2: {
        foo: 3,
        bar: 4,
        anotherfoo: 8,
      },
      module3: {
        foo: 7,
        bar: 6,
        anotherfoo: 3,
      },
      module4: {
        submodule: {
          foo: 9,
          bar: 0,
          anotherfoo: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  },
]

const dotPaths = ["module1", "module4.submodule"]
const res = arr.map((el) =>
  dotPaths.map((dotPath) => getDotPath(dotPath, el.module))
)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: expected output should  be like module1:{ foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        anotherfoo: 5,},
module4: {
          foo: 9,
          bar: 0,
          anotherfoo: 1,
        },